# Embedded Systems in Linux: fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, embedded

Currently, I am working on programming Embedded C in Linux environment. I am trying to read input data from a joystick.
Before, when I created a header file joystick.h with all definitions and I initialized the joystick inside the main function (the header file is not compiled). Everything was okay and smooth.

However, when I refactored the code by putting initialization in joystick.c (which included joystick.h) and call the initialization function in main() from joystick.h. There was an error "fatal error: asm/types.h: No such file or directory". This error happened after creating joystick.c file because the joystick.c was added to Makefile to compile.

I tried several ways to fix this such as:

- add "export ARCH=x86_64"
- change asm -> asm-generic
  Those did not work.

So how can I fix this error?

Best regards, Huy Nguyen.

Comment: You should only ever include <sys/types.h> never anything with asm in the name directly.

Comment: You need to post the code for `#include` used by the various files and also the header guards used if any.

Comment: I am sorry for replying late. It seemed that when replacing asm/types.h by sys/types.h, it worked. But the linux/input.h again no such file or directory.

Comment: Compiler diagnostics contain more information than you have provided here, and are an essential tool for debugging.  You need to post the entire build diagnostic output.

Comment: "_the header file is not compiled_" is not strictly true, if it Is `#include`'ed, then the content will be processed by the compilation of whatever it is included in.  The statement is in any case redundant; anyone who could answer knows how C compilation and linking work.

Comment: Also, post a) the code that worked, b) the broken code.  How can we tell what the error is from your _description_ of code?  Sounds like you are "cargo-cult" programming.  Your first mistake is probably using Linux's sledgehammer for a simple nut of an application.

Comment: Hello everyone, I discovered the error comes from 2 Makefiles that conflict each other. I have a Makefile of a component in the system and a Makefile for the whole system. What I should have done was to add .c file to the Makefile of the component rather than the other one.